# Create service to generate an XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I am trying to create a service which will generate an XML file using C#.

```
    String status = "";
    String display = "";
    int procID = -1;
    String canStop = "";
    String canShut = "";

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        services.Add("SQLWriter");
        services.Add("wbengine");
        services.Add("CcmExec");
        services.Add("bthserv");
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        StartingUp();
    }

    void StartingUp()
    {
        //File.Delete(@"OnStart.txt");
        //File.Delete(@"OnStop.txt");
        //File.Delete(@"Service.xml");
        //System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt");

        WriteToXml();

            System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Test 1.txt");

        EventLog.CreateEventSource("Service Extrator", "MyNewLog");
        EventLog.WriteEntry("FFS please work"); 
        timer1.Start();     
    }

    public void MonitorService(String SERVICENAME)
    {
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(SERVICENAME);

        switch (sc.Status)
        {
            case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
                status = "Running";
                Console.Write("Running"); 
                break;
            case ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped:
                status = "Stopped";
                Console.Write("Stopped");
                break;
            case ServiceControllerStatus.Paused:
                status = "Paused";
                Console.Write("Paused");
                break;
            case ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending:
                status = "Stopping";
                Console.Write("Stopping");
                break;
            case ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending:
                status = "Starting";
                Console.Write("Starting");
                break;
            default:
                status = "Status Changing";
                Console.Write("Status Changing");
                break;
        }
        display = sc.DisplayName;
        try
        {
            procID = Process.GetProcessesByName(SERVICENAME)[0].Id;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            procID = -1;
        }

        bool Cstop = sc.CanStop;
        if (Cstop)
        {
            canStop = "True";
        }
        else
            canStop = "False";
        bool CanShut = sc.CanShutdown;
        if (CanShut)
        {
            canShut = "True";
        }
        else
            canShut = "False";
        //WriteToXml(SERVICENAME);
    }

    public void WriteToXml()
    {
        System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Test 2.txt");

        XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
        xmlWriterSettings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("Service.xml", xmlWriterSettings))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Services");
            System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Test 3.txt");

            foreach (String SERVICENAME in services)
            {
                MonitorService(SERVICENAME);
                writer.WriteStartElement("Service");

                writer.WriteElementString("Name", SERVICENAME);   // <-- These are new
                writer.WriteElementString("Pid", procID.ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("Description", display);
                writer.WriteElementString("Status", status);
                writer.WriteElementString("CanbeShutdown", canShut);
                writer.WriteElementString("CanbeStopped", canStop);

                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
        //MessageBox.Show("Service data written to XML file");
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WriteToXml();
    }
}
```

}

But for some reason it seem to be able to create all the text files but not generate the XML file.

Does anyone have an idea why XML does not work well with services or if it can and what i am doing wrong?

Any advice?

Comment: what is services?? a list??

Comment: It is an Array which is being used

Comment: You should probably use [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to create the file names.

Comment: Can you show me an example please? @JohnnyMopp

Comment: `System.IO.File.Create(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Test 1.txt"));` It just ensures the directory separator char is there. Not sure if that's the issue here, but it can't hurt.

Comment: The text files arnt the issue, sorry its the generation of the XML, the txt files are appearing fine, the code doesnt seem to want to generate the xml file @JohnnyMopp

Comment: Also, you don't give a full path to `XmlWriter.Create`.

Comment: This is because i want it to output to the release folder instead of a specific location. @JohnnyMopp